# How can I get thumbnails of a website from its URL?

Tags: url, screenshot

I want to save the thumbnails of a website by just entering their urls , e.g if I enter http://www.google.com , it should generate the thumbnail of the google search page .

One such API that I was using till now is **http://counter2.goingup.com/thumboo/image.php**.
A sample url for that :

[http://counter2.goingup.com/thumboo/image.php?i=1f899e4e1abf9473ccae69de4f3ec1ca|||www.google.com|||80x50](http://counter2.goingup.com/thumboo/image.php?i=1f899e4e1abf9473ccae69de4f3ec1ca%7C%7C%7Cwww.google.com%7C%7C%7C80x50)

But , off late it's showing the error "URL not found" . Do anybody know what exacly has gone wrong with this API ?

Is there any other such convenient third party API out there which can be of some help to me . By convenient , I mean, it should not show a lame **Screenshot queued up** message everytime it fails to find any pre-existent snapshot for that website in their db.

Comment: you can use something like https://urlbox.io - screenshot service API. Its got easy to integrate API and generates thumbnails as per your requirement.

Answer (score 6):

Use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to create screenshots. PhantomJS comes with an example called `rasterize.js`, which does exactly this. Example:

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html clock.png
```

Docs [here](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html). Related projects including web services [here](http://phantomjs.org/related-projects.html).

Comment: Any idea how to do that for a site that one is logged into?

Answer (score 1):

http://snapit.io works well, and gives you historical caching on a CDN. For example this URL would look like

http://www.snapit.io/snaps?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907170/get-thumbnails-of-a-website-from-their-urls

if you wanted a thumbnail of 200x200 pixels (keeping aspect ratio) you could do

http://www.snapit.io/snaps?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907170/get-thumbnails-of-a-website-from-their-urls&max_width=200&max_height=200

There's a lot of other services just like this out there, most require a subscription for any substantial amount of use though (including snapit.io), http://url2png.com, http://www.shrinktheweb.com, http://www.thumbalizr.com.

Comment: Does not exist anymore